# How can you access an environment variable that has a space in its name in bash?

Tags: bash, jenkins

Running `env` returns "Clear Workspace=true". How can I access it in bash? FYI, it's coming from a Jenkins Parameterized Build parameter name. `${Clear Workspace}` does not appear to work.

Also, how is Jenkins even able to create this environment variable? Running `Clear Workspace=true` in bash obviously doesn't work as it tries to run the "Clear" command with an argument of "Workspace=true".

I could of course make the job parameter name Clear_Workspace, but it's presented in a form to the user, so I'd rather not. Also, the Maven Build Plugin for Jenkins has several parameter names with spaces in them, so it must be possible to access them somehow.

Comment: I was able to manually set one via `env foo\ bar=3` but not yet found a way to echo it.

Comment: @mbratch You're mistaken. Just because the command didn't give an error doesn't imply that you were able to *set* it.  Try saying `env`; do you find it?

Comment: @devnull... sure, ok. Really no need to be snarky here. But when I run the command, `env` gives a list as output and it shows `foo bar=3` at the bottom of the list of variables. So it sort of acts like it worked. It does behave a little oddly.

Comment: @devnull: I agree with mbratch.  By using `env "foo bar=3" bash`.  I was able to create a shell with "foo bar" in the environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simulate this bit of fun with the `env` command

```
env Clear\ Workspace=true bash
```

That will give you a shell with the environment variable set.

A hacky way, which should work up to bash 4.0, to get the environment variable value back out is:

```
declare -p Clear\ Workspace | sed -e "s/^declare -x Clear Workspace=\"//;s/\"$//"
```

Bash versions starting with 4.0 will instead return an error and are unable to extract such environment variables in that way.

Other than that you'd need to use either a native code program or a scripting language to pull it out, e.g.

```
ruby -e "puts ENV['Clear Workspace']"
```

Which is much less hacky... also if you don't have ruby

```
perl -e 'print "$ENV{\"Clear Workspace\"}\n";'
```

also

```
python -c 'import os; print os.environ["Clear Workspace"]'
```

And here is a native code version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) 
{
  char **env;
  char *target;
  int len;
  if (argc != 2) 
  {
    printf("Syntax: %s name\n", argv[0]);
    return 2;
  }
  len = strlen(argv[1]);
  target = calloc(len+2,sizeof(char));
  strncpy(target,argv[1],len+2);
  target[len++] = '=';
  target[len] = '0';
  for (env = envp; *env != 0; env++) 
  {
    char *thisEnv = *env;
    if (strncmp(thisEnv,target,len)==0)
    {
      printf("%s\n",thisEnv+len);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I'm restricted to bash, as it's part of a Jenkins build job, so I may end up taking your hacky declare | sed solution. I'm considering whether it's worth it in order to save the user from seeing an underscore...

Comment: there's usually a ruby/perl/python on the path... you could test for them and then fall back to the hack if one of them is missing... Or you could use a HEREDOC to create a temporary source file that you then compile either with `gcc` or `javac` and then execute... but I think testing for ruby/python/perl with fallback to declare hack will get you a nice solution

Comment: Ah, thanks Stephen. I wasn't aware you could jump into a scripting language in a Jenkins job. Very handy. If there isn't one already there, I'll get Python installed.

Comment: This answer is old and probably needs an update. Recent versions of bash (5.0+? Maybe even 4.0+?) probably fixed a bug and fetching environment variables with spaces doesn't work any longer: `env Clear\ Workspace=true bash -c 'declare -p Clear\ Workspace'` returns `bash: line 1: declare: Clear Workspace: not found`.

Answer (score 1):

bash is not the only language that can manipulate the environment:

```
$ perl -e '$ENV{"Clear Workspace"}="true"; system "env"' | grep Clear
Clear Workspace=true
```

If you're in a shell, you can always parse the output of `env` (untested)

```
value=$(env | while IFS="=" read -r var value; do
                  if [[ $var = "Clear Workspace" ]]; then
                      echo "$value"
                      break
                  fi
              done )
```

Comment: I'm restricted to using bash, as it's part of a Jenkins job. Parsing env sounds awkward, but may be the only solution available to me.

Comment: bash is just a tool that calls other programs. Surely you can write a bash script that invokes a perl/ruby/python program.

Comment: I could, assuming one of those is installed on the server. I'd have to either write a script and put it somewhere on the server and reference it or write it in the bash field of the job and have the interpreter parse it, both of which are not ideal. Also, bash is not just a tool that calls other programs. You can do a bunch of other things with it. I was looking for a simple bash solution.

Answer (score 0):

Java supports passing environment variables with spaces in names to processes. Here's an example that proves it:

Given /tmp/test

```
#!/bin/sh
env > /tmp/test.out
```

and Test.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception     {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/tmp/test");
        Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
        env.put("a b", "true");
        pb.directory(new File("/tmp"));
        Process p = pb.start();
    }
}
```

run

```
> javac Test.java
> java Test
> grep "a b" /tmp/test.out 
a b=true
```

[Jenkins uses the same functionality to start processes](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/stable/core/src/main/java/hudson/Proc.java#L226).

For you to access those from a pure shell, without using python, ruby, etc however, I am not sure. I haven't been able to achieve it yet.

You may wish to convert those to variable without spaces as those have better portability guarantee.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect the Maven Build Plugin is able to use this, but I'm restricted to bash, as it's just part of a build job, not a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The Following command will return the value of the environment variable " **Clear Workspace** ":

```
set | grep "Clear Workspace" | awk -F'=' '{print $NF}'
```

You can assign to another variable without space and use for your purpose :

```
export Clear_Workspace=\`set | grep "Clear Workspace" | awk -F'=' '{print $NF}'\`
```

Give a try.

Answer (score -1):

Jenkins is probably creating *something* other than an *environment variable*.

You cannot have spaces in environment variables.  Quoting http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html:

> Environment variable names used by the utilities in the Shell and
>   Utilities volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 consist solely of uppercase
>   letters, digits, and the '_' (underscore) from the characters defined
>   in Portable Character Set and do not begin with a digit.

Comment: I think @mbratch has proven that you can have a space in an environment variable name (see comments on question). Just because "Environment variable names used by the utilities in the Shell and Utilities volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 consist solely of uppercase letters, digits, and the underscore", this does not mean that _all_ environment variables _must_ consist solely of those characters.