# Jenkins Parameterized Variable Name Convert Whitespace to Underscore

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I am trying to figure out something that I believe should be pretty simple but I think my google foo is falling weak on. When creating a parameterized value in Jenkins you find that the "Name" becomes the name of the environment variable in the shell/bash session you may want to run. My problem is that when using Descriptive Naming like "Target Thing" there is a whitespace in the name.

I do note that in the shell/bash environment that there is a variable, but it is not set.

#### OUTPUT

```
+ declare -p
declare -x Target Thing
declare -x New Thing Directory Name
```

*Note: there is no following value*

Now I imagine that this might be a limitation of the Shell/Bash environments. So my questions are these:

1. Is there a setting I can place in to the environment to at least catch the value such that I can then figure out on how to pull it out.
2. Is there a setting in Jenkins that will allow me to replace the spaces in the name with another character like an underscore "_".
3. If not the above underscore; is there a setting or plugin that will allow me to specify the variable name separate from the name I enter as a descriptor.

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468397/how-can-you-access-an-environment-variable-that-has-a-space-in-its-name-in-bash ...But its going to be a pain... all the best :)

Comment: I did, but as shown above the value doesn't make it into the environment :-/. All those suggestions rely on the fact that it is at least captured.

Comment: Actually it does ....I tried it and i actually found it in env variables you can confirm it  using `echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env')` you can find it there ...

Comment: Nope, Didn't work :-(, in fact it doesn't even show that Variable in the Environment. Only the `declare -p` as shown above shows it. This is why I think it might be a Shell/Bash Environment setting. My Jenkins run's inside a Docker Container so the environment might be more slim than a full install of Linux elsewhere.