# Can a shell variable have spaces in name?

Tags: bash, variables, environment-variables

I would like to export a variable name with spaces. Is it possible in shell `export` command?

```
{'Truststore Filename': '/hom/truststore.jks', 'Truststore Password': 'pass'}
```

```
$ export 'Truststore Password'=clientpass
-bash: export: `Truststore Password=clientpass': not a valid identifier
```

But i would like to export the variables using `export` command because we have more than more than one variable to be exported which has spaces in names.

However, the following way works.

```
$ env 'Truststore Password'=clientpass 'Truststore Filename'=/hom/truststore.jks python3 script.py
```

Comment: *not a valid identifier*

Comment: So, it is possible to have a variable name with space  ?  Please note that env command worked

Comment: I recommend starting by reading documentation and not letting others read it to you.

Comment: Shells don't make this obvious, but the environment is not just a set of shell variables; it's a set of strings that contain `=`. Shells, however, expose the subset of environment strings whose pre-`=` portion is a valid identifier *as* variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not possible, as [a variable in bash cannot have a name that includes spaces](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html#index-name):

> `name`
>
> A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. `Name`s are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an `identifier`.

`env`, as you noticed, plays by different rules:

> Environment variable names can be empty, and can contain any
>   characters other than ‘=’ and ASCII NUL. However, it is wise to **limit
>   yourself to names that consist solely of underscores, digits, and ASCII
>   letters, and that begin with a non-digit, as applications like the shell
>   do not work well with other names**.

(source: `info '(coreutils) env invocation'`; emphasis mine)

Case in point, [here's another post with an answer about how much of a pain it is to grab the output of an environment variable with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18469375/5889131)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any alternative to that ?  I tried with env and it worked for me

Comment: Link: [`info env`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html#env-invocation)

Comment: I added some info about what `env` accepts. It's much more liberal, but they're pretty much unusable variables for shell purposes.